# How does this code print 404?

Tags: c, gcc

I copied this below code from Stack Overflow's **404 Not Found Error Page**.

```
# define v putchar
# define print(x)
main(){v(4+v(v(52)-4));return 0;}/*
#>+++++++4+[>++++++<-]>
++++.----.++++.*/
print(202*2);exit();
#define/*>.@*/exit()
```

The above code compiles fine and prints **404** on the console. I thought the statement **print(202*2);** is responsible for printing **404**, but I am not right because changing the numbers in this statement also prints **404**.

Could somebody help me to understand this code and how it prints **404**?

Am posting the compilation output for your reference as there are comments saying this code doesn't compile. The file containing above code is **Test.c**.

> gcc Test.c -o Test
>
> Test.c:3:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int] 
>   main(){v(4+v(v(52)-4));return 0;}/*  ^ Test.c: In function ‘main’:
>   Test.c:1:12: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘putchar’
>   [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]  # define v putchar
>               ^ Test.c:3:8: note: in expansion of macro ‘v’  main(){v(4+v(v(52)-4));return 0;}/*
>           ^ Test.c: At top level: Test.c:6:14: warning: data definition has no type or storage class  print(202*2);exit();
>                 ^ Test.c:6:14: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘exit’ [-Wimplicit-int] Test.c:6:14: warning:
>   conflicting types for built-in function ‘exit’
>
> ./Test
>
> 404

Comment: putchar(52) outputs 4; 52-4 = 48; putchar(48) outputs 0; 48+4 = 52; putchar(52) outpus 4 again.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252184/whats-the-joke-in-the-stack-overflow-404-page-code

Comment: Just asking: Dear Migration to MSO voters: can you please add a little justification? I think I'm missing something here on why is should be migrated?

Comment: @SouravGhosh; It should be migrated because it has been asked on meta stackoverflow and there are some good answer already there.

Comment: It doesn't. The code won't compile for multiple reasons. I doubt the code is even C.

Comment: @haccks Thanks, but just one thought, does that migration not allow for more questions on SO for this in future?

Comment: @Lundin - I was able to compile the code with few warnings using gcc and execute it successfully.

Comment: @Beginner No, it is impossible to compile this on a standard-compliant C compiler without rewriting most of it.

Comment: @SouravGhosh; Does SO meant for such questions? And if you think you can answer better than the answers provided on meta then you are welcome.

Comment: @Beginner Compile it as C language instead of GNU language: `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors`.

Comment: I made a much more intricate example which does compile cleanly on a standard compliant compiler. Added to my answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# define v putchar
```

this defines `v` as the `putchar()` function. It prints a character and returns it.

```
# define print(x)
```

this defines `print(x)` as nothing (so `print(202*2)` means nothing)

```
main(){v(4+v(v(52)-4));return 0;}/*
```

this could be rewritten as:

```
main()
{
  putchar(4 + putchar(putchar(52) - 4));
  return 0;
}
```

it is using ASCII codes to print '4' (code 52), '0' (code 52 - 4 = 38) and again '4', so "404".

That line ends with a `/*` starting a comment the continues through the next two lines:

```
#>+++++++4+[>++++++<-]>
++++.----.++++.*/
```

The line below turns out empty, but it is a bit tricky because `exit()` is defined as empty *AFTER* the line itself. That works because the C preprocessor runs *BEFORE* the compilation.

```
print(202*2);exit();
```

The line below defines `exit()` as empty, used on the line above.

```
#define/*>.@*/exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

<sup>*Cannot use a meta-question as dupe, so blatantly copying from [the MSO answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252187/2173917).*</sup>

Since this is tagged [c](/questions/tagged/c) and mentioned "compiled", so just extracting the C part of it.

**Credits: [Mark Rushakoff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/126042/mark-rushakoff) is the [original author of the polyglot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27846).**

> The C code is fairly easy to read, but even easier if you run it
>   through a preprocessor:
>
> ```
> main(){putchar(4+putchar(putchar(52)-4));return 0;};exit();
> ```
>
> Your standard `main` function is declared there, and `exit` is also
>   declared as a function with an implicit return type of `int` (`exit`
>   is effectively ignored).
>
> `putchar` was used because you don't need any `#include` to use it;
>   you give it an integer argument and it puts the corresponding ASCII
>   character to stdout and returns the same value you gave it.  So, we
>   put 52 (which is `4`); then we subtract 4 and output `0`; then we add
>   4 to output `4` again.

Also, a little more elboration, from [Cole Johnson's]
(https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1350209/cole-johnson) [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252191/2173917)

> Disregarding all of that, when we reformat the code a bit, and replace
>   `52` with its ASCII equivalent (`'4'`), we get:
>
> ```
> int main() {
>     putchar(4 + putchar(putchar('4') - 4));
>     return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> As for the `putchar` declaration, it is defined by the standard to
>   return it's input, like `realloc`. First, this program prints a `4`,
>   then takes the ASCII value (`52`), subtracts 4 (`48`), prints that
>   (ASCII `0`), adds 4 (`52`), prints that (`4`), then finally
>   terminates. This results in the following output:
>
> ```
> 404
> ```
>
> As for this polyglot being valid **C++**, unfortunately, it is not as
>   **C++** requires an explicit return type for functions. This program takes advantage of the fact that **C** requires functions without an
>   explicit return type to be `int`.

Comment: Should vote for transfer onto meta then. Where it can be closed as a dup.

Comment: @StoryTeller But it __is__ a valid question in SO. it's about the code understanding, not about the working of SO....right? I understand the context is overlapping, but it's not OT here, either...What do you think?

Comment: I agree this is a valid topic in SO ^^. Maybe make a wiki answer. In fact this is the meta question that is off topic.

Comment: I think that we should not be answering questions over and over again. This overlaps with meta, and meta has a perfect answer for it.

Comment: If the code were ever likely to be encountered in "The Real World™" then it should stay here. Given the code's SO specificity, Meta is probably the place for it.

Answer (score 1):

The code cannot compile on a standard C compiler, such as `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors`.

1) main must return int on hosted systems.
2) putchar() must have `#include <stdio.h>`.
3) You can't write semicolons outside functions.

After fixing these beginner-level bugs and removing all superfluous fluff that doesn't do anything but creating compiler errors, we are left with this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define v putchar
int main(){v(4+v(v(52)-4));return 0;}
```

This revolves around putchar returning the character written:

```
putchar(4+putchar(putchar(52)-4));
```

- 52 is ASCII for `'4'`. Print 4.
- 52 - 4 = 48, ASCII for `0`. Print 0.
- 4 + 48 = 52. Again print 4.

And that's it. Very bleak as far as obfuscation attempts go.

---

Proper, standard-compliant obfuscation would rather look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iso646.h>

??=define not_found_404(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)a%:%:b%:%:c%:%:d%:%:e%:%:f(\
(g%:%:h%:%:i%:%:j<::>)<%'$'+d##o%:%:e not "good",g??=??=ompl ??-- -0163l,\
((void)(0xBAD bito##b not "bad"),not "ugly")??>,(g%:%:h%:%:i%:%:j??(??)){\
((c%:%:d%:%:e)- -not "lost")     <:??=a??) -??-??- '<',\
((c%:%:d%:%:e)- -not "found")    <:??=b??) -??-??- 'B',\
((c%:%:d%:%:e)- -not 0xDEADC0DE) <:??=c??) -??-??- '5',\
((c%:%:d%:%:e)- -6##6##6 xo##b- -6##6##6)%>)

int main()
{
  not_found_404(p,r,i,n,t,f,c,h,a,r);  
}
```

Comment: "You can't write semicolons outside functions.", What ? you mean instructions ? By the way, proto of `main()` should be `int main(void);` in this case so you are not compliant :p.

Comment: @Stargateur `print(202*2);exit();` gets interpreted as `;exit();` which is nonsense. GCC gives the error "ISO C does not allow extra ';' outside of a function". And no, the form of main() may take any parameters and the standard isn't really clear. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/584518

Comment: This is not an obfuscation attempt. It's a polyglot code.

Comment: @bolov No it isn't, as demonstrated above. A polyglot is code that compiles in multiple languages.

Comment: @Lundin https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27846/254429 it runs and has the same output in Befunge-93, Brainf*ck, Python, Ruby, Perl, and C. Okey I get your point not standard C, but still...

Answer (score 0):

you have defined V as putchar() which take ascii code of char to be printed and return ascii value of printed char. execution of your program will start from the main as bellow
first v(52) will print 4 and return 52
second v(52-4) will print 0 (48 is ascii value of 0) and return 48
finally it will call to v(48+4) will print 4 as 52 is ascii value of '4'.